# How can I take an HTML defined function and call it in my .js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a function in my .js file that I defined in my HTML file.
This is where I create the function:

```
    <script>
      function customAlert(msg,duration)
      {
        var styler = document.createElement("div");
        time=duration*1000
        styler.setAttribute("style","border: solid 3px Blue;width:auto;height:auto;top:50%;left:40%;background-color:#444;color:Silver");
        styler.innerHTML = "<h1>"+msg+"</h1>";
        setTimeout(function()
        {
          styler.parentNode.removeChild(styler);
        },time);
        document.body.appendChild(styler);
      }
    </script>
```

this is where I need the function to be called:

```
io.on("disconnect", function() {
  customAlert(userLeftmessage, "2000")
});
```

Is there a way to do this? As you might be a ble to tell, I'm neew to HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Insert your script file after `script` section.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the .js file after this script block, the function will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the script file after the HTML script.

```js
// Javascript
cl("This is a log from external script file.");
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script>
  function cl(input) {
    console.log(input);
  }
</script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```